# Puma Request Logging

Tags: logging, bundler, rack, puma, foreman

I do `foreman start` to run my Rack app.

My `Procfile` has one line: `web: bundle exec puma`.

But, when I make a request, Puma doesn't log it to standard output (stdout).

Answer (score 1):

On my MacBook Air, which I use for local development, I start the server with:

```
eval $(cat .env) bundle exec puma --debug -v
```

And, I aliased that to `bp`.

See `puma --help` for more info.